# Travel Plans To take along my wife to UK from Paris

Tags: visas, uk, eu-citizens

I am a Portuguese Passport Holder and and at present on visit to my relatives in Paris and my wife is holding Indian Passport and had traveled along with me to Paris on Schengen Visa which was valid for 20 days And now we are planning to visit our next relatives in UK but my wife's Schengen Visa expired. So need information how we can travel to UK. And can my wife apply for UK visa from Paris now?

Comment: Wouldn't an EU family member visa be easier? See [europa.eu](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/residence/worker-pensioner/non-eu-family-members/index_en.htm)

Answer (score 3):

As an EU national you can provide your wife with two options for visiting the UK...

1. **Apply as a Standard Visitor**, to do this she can create an account at the Foreign Office's site [Visa4U](https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk/home/welcome) and fill out the
   form.  At the drop-down on the first page, select "Visit" and then
   "General Visitor" (or "Family Visitor" if you have carefully read
   the guidance).  The form will know what to do after that.
2. **Apply as a EEA/Swiss Family Member**, it's the same site.  At the drop-down on the first page, select "Other" and then "EEA/Swiss
   Family Member".  The form will fork to a family permit application.

In both cases, the application will show you where the nearest Visa Facilitation Centre is and the VFS will send the app to the hub in Croydon or Paris.  The family permit is free, but you need to accompany her (or join her) at the border.  She can visit the UK independently on a Standard Visitor visa.

Tip: once you have completed the application and made your appointment, you can go and create an account at the VFS site (Teleperformance).  This will speed up your application.

Tip: read the guidance before selecting "Family Visitor". It's hard to back up and start over.  There's a link to the guidance given when you create an account.

Tip:  Overall, they don't cut you any slack from not reading the guidance. We have lots of questions here to unsnarl something that was clearly spelled out and could have been avoided.  Keep a copy of the guidance open in another window and you'll be fine.