# I am German citizen and my wife is non EU with german spouse residence permit. Does she need a visa for visiting UK?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, german-citizens

My wife is from India and I am German. We both live in Germany and she has a German residence permit through our marriage. We both plan to visit UK. Does she need a visa to visit UK?

Comment: Would you be travelling to the UK together, or would she be going there on her own?

Comment: We would like to go together.

Comment: Yes she does.  We have an answer already prepared for you.  You can read it here http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52069/travel-plans-to-take-along-my-wife-to-uk-from-paris/52070#52070

Comment: When i apply for standard Visa do i need to pay the Fee?

Comment: The UK Visitor (Standard) attracts a fee from all applicants; the family permit is free

Comment: So the family permit can also be taken for short term tourism purposes?

Comment: @stutter Yes, in fact you do not even need to justify the purpose of your trip for the family permit, only that your wife is your wife and that you are an EU citizen. That's it (at least in theory).

Comment: Thank you so much. Last time she went to UK to meet her friends, she took a tourist visa from Berlin which costed us 209 euros and her passport was away for 21 days. She got it for six months but i find it just ridiculous amount of money and time.

Comment: @stutter Unfortunately, while visas for family members are supposed to be issued quickly as far as EU law is concerned, the UK has had serious problems with that in the past and it might still take longer to get the family permit. If you don't mind the money and requirements, a Standard Visitor visa might still be quicker.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, she almost certainly needs a visa. The [main exception](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card) is for people who hold a residence card as “family member of an EU citizen” (in German “*Aufenthaltskarte für Familienangehörige eines Unionsbürgers*”) but that wouldn't typically be the case of the spouse of a German citizen in Germany.

Other German residence permit holders fall under the regular rules based on their citizenship, which for an Indian citizen, means that a visa is required to enter the UK.

But since you would be travelling together, she would be covered by your right to free movement as an EU citizen and she could apply for an [EEA family permit](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/overview) instead of a Standard Visitor visa. The family permit has simpler requirements and is free of charge but was unfortunately very long to obtain in the past (not sure about the current status of all this).

Comment: her residence permit is  aufenthaltserlaubnis §28 abs 1 Nr 1

Comment: @stutter Yes, that makes sense, it means that your wife does need a visa. The residence card I mentioned is defined in another statute, § 5 Abs. 1 Freizügigkeitsgesetz/EU.

Comment: so are there different resident cards being given out in germany?

Comment: @stutter And in all other EU countries as well, because EU rules do not apply to EU citizens in their own country. Incidentally, everything else is called a “permit” (“Erlaubnis”), only the residence title for family members of EU citizens is called an “Aufenthaltskarte”.

Comment: Thanks for all the information. That was really helpful @relaxed

Comment: @stutter if you plan to visit UK using the residence card (assuming is the right one in order to don't need a visa), I strongly suggest to bring with you also a multilingual certification marriage, so you can prove to the officer your marriage status with your wife. This is written also inside the gov.uk link and I read on other forums that is checked